# Fetch all values based on key in multidimensional array Javascript with higest value to that key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have try the following code and i want to get the the record with latest date.
In the following example i need the record with latest and same date
mean array with keys 2 and 5.
I have try the following but dont get success.

```
var arr = [];

arr['0'] = { label : '2003', Date : '2003-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['1'] = { label : '2007', Date : '2003-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['2'] = { label : '2009', Date : '2010-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['3'] = { label : '2008', Date : '2005-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['4'] = { label : '2008', Date : '2005-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['5'] = { label : '2010', Date : '2010-11-17 00:00:00'};

console.log(arr);

var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return (moment(a.Date).isAfter(b.Date));
}, 0);

console.log(max);
```

Comment: can you give an expected solution?

Comment: The result should contain only values with date 2010-11-17 00:00:00

Comment: sort on "label" first and then find duplicated "Date"

Comment: The label is same for different dates so sorting on this is not working
I need to get the record with latest date and same date

Comment: (moment(a.Date).isAfter(b.Date)) returns boolean so the value of max would be a boolean here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort and filter your array:

```js
var arr = [];
arr['0'] = { label : '2003', Date : '2003-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['1'] = { label : '2007', Date : '2003-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['2'] = { label : '2009', Date : '2010-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['3'] = { label : '2008', Date : '2005-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['4'] = { label : '2008', Date : '2005-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['5'] = { label : '2010', Date : '2010-11-17 00:00:00'};

var max = arr
  .sort((a, b) => moment(a.Date).isAfter(b.Date))
  .filter((elem, index, arr) => elem.Date === arr[arr.length - 1].Date);

console.log(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

First index the array based on the date

```
var dateMap = {};
arr.forEach( function(item){
  dateMap[ item.Date ] = dateMap[ item.Date ] || [];
  dateMap[ item.Date ].push( item );
});
```

Now sort the keys, simple string sort will do

```
var keys = Object.keys( dateMap );
keys.sort();
```

Since the array is sorted in ascending order, get the last key with max value

```
var maxDate = keys.pop();
```

Now get all the array items associated with this max date

```
return dateMap[ maxDate ];
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple `reduce` function will do the job by comparing the current date with a retained maximum (using the accumulator to store the max value).  For very large arrays this should be faster than sorting and filtering, since it only needs to access the array once.

```
var max = arr.reduce((max, d) => max > d.Date ? max : d.Date, 0);
```

An equivalent version in more verbose code:

```
var max = arr.reduce(function(max, d) {
    if (max > d.Date) {
    return max;
    } else { 
        return d.Date;
    }
}, 0);
```

If you need the full value, you can use an object as the accumulator (note the change to the initial accumulator value):

```
var max = arr.reduce((max, d) => max.Date > d.Date ? max : d, {Date: 0});
```

or

```
var max = arr.reduce(function(max, d) {
    if (max.Date > d.Date) {
    return max;
    } else { 
        return d;
    }
}, {Date: 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to get the object with maximum date and then use `array#filter` to get the all the objects with that date.

```js
var arr = [];

arr['0'] = { label : '2003', Date : '2003-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['1'] = { label : '2007', Date : '2003-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['2'] = { label : '2009', Date : '2010-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['3'] = { label : '2008', Date : '2005-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['4'] = { label : '2008', Date : '2005-11-17 00:00:00'};
arr['5'] = { label : '2010', Date : '2010-11-17 00:00:00'};

var max = arr.reduce(function(prev,cur){
    return moment(prev.Date).isAfter(moment(cur.Date)) ? prev : cur;
});

var result = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return max.Date === obj.Date;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `Math.max`, `map` and `filter`.

```js
var arr = [];
arr['0'] = { label: '2003', Date: '2003-11-17 00:00:00' };
arr['1'] = { label: '2007', Date: '2003-11-17 00:00:00' };
arr['2'] = { label: '2009', Date: '2010-11-17 00:00:00' };
arr['3'] = { label: '2008', Date: '2005-11-17 00:00:00' };
arr['4'] = { label: '2008', Date: '2005-11-17 00:00:00' };
arr['5'] = { label: '2010', Date: '2010-11-17 00:00:00' };

//Get max year
var year = Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function(e) { return new Date(e.Date.replace(" ","T")).getFullYear() }));
//Filter array based on year
console.log(arr.filter(function (a,b) { return new Date(a.Date.replace(" ","T")).getFullYear() === year }))
```